# Documentation of the TFS 2012 Web Access URLs

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access, tfs-2012

I want to  a URL that points to a workitem, or a workitem query result. In TFS 2010 the URLs were like this

```
 http://<server>:8080/tfs/web/UI/Pages/WorkItems/QueryResultNW.aspx?...
```

But TFS 2012 said that URL is from an earlier version of Web Access. What are the corresponding TFS 2012 URLs? Is this documented anywhere?